# Vetor dentro de vetor. O que ele faz nesse contexto?

Tags: java, array

Foi perguntado a 40 alunos o nível de qualidade da comida na cantina estudantil, em uma escala de 0 a 10. ( 1 significando horrorosa e 10 significando  excelente). Coloque as quarenta respostas em um array inteiro e resuma os resultados da pesquisa.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    final int tamanhoResposta = 40, frequencySize = 11;
    int response[] = {5, 10, 6, 7, 3, 7,5 ,6 ,3, 10, 4,5,4,9,8,7,5,6,5,6,4,5,6,7,8,4,3,8,9,10,9,6,5,3,9,5,9,10};
    int frequency[] ={0};


    for(int i = 0; i < tamanhoResposta; i++){
        ++frequency[response[i]];
    }

    System.out.println(" Avaliação ===================== Frequência " );
    for(int ii = 0; ii < frequencySize; ii++){
        System.out.println(ii + " ");
        System.out.println(frequency[ii]);
    }
```

Eu não entendi para que serve essa parte, mas o que isso faz?

```
++frequency[response[i]];
```

Ele dá essa exceção:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5

Comment: O downvoter podia aproveitar que passou por aqui e responder a pergunta ou explicar como ela pode ser melhorada.

Comment: downvoter? Não entendo...

Comment: @AlineGonzaga sua pergunta teve 5 votos positivos e um negativo, totalizando 4 pontos até o momento. O que o Caffé sugeriu no comentário dele, é que o _downvoter_ (a pessoa que votou negativo) se manifestasse para ajudar a resolver ou melhorar a questão.

Comment: Também acho. Valeu por me explicar o termo.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O operador `++` é um incrementador. Se você tem uma variável chamada `x` pode fazer:

```
x++;
```

que o mesmo que:

```
x += 1;
```

que é o mesmo que:

```
x = x + 1;
```

que é o mesmo que:

```
++x;
```

A diferença é o que o último faz o incremento de um antes de usar o valor da variável. Isso é útil em uma expressão, mas não em um *statement*, como é o caso utilizado. Ou seja, nesse caso poderia ter escrito `frequency[response[i]]++;` que dava no mesmo. Ou poderia ter escrito `frequency[response[i]] = frequency[response[i]] + 1;`. Bem mais longo, né?

Obviamente o que ele está incrementando é um elemento do *array* `frequency`. Conhece *arrays*, né? Qual é esse elemento? É o primeiro elemento? Ou seja, é o 0? É o 1? Ele é determinado por uma variável. No caso é a `response[i];`, que por sua vez também é um elemento de um *array*. Então ele está pegando o elemento de `response` determinado por `i`, e esse elemento está sendo usado como índice de `frequency`.

Não confunda o *array* com seus elementos. Todos são variáveis. O *array* é uma variável que contém um porção de variáveis, mas cada elemento é uma variável individual.

Uma forma diferente de escrever a mesma coisa:

```
int x = response[i];
int y = frequency[x];
y = y + 1;
frequency[x] = y;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Array/Increment.java).

Ficou mais claro agora?

Comment: Ficou mais claro, mas por que eu iria colocar um vetor dentro de um mesmo vetor? preciso ler só mais um pouco sobre isso e escolho a resposta...

Comment: Primeiro, qual o problema de ter um vetor dentro de outro vetor? Um vetor é só uma coleção de dados. Quais dados podem ter dentro de um vetor? Qualquer coisa pode estar ali. Inclusive outro vetor. Uma matriz não é o vetor de vetores? Isto é uma simplificação, mas é uma forma de entender a questão. Mas neste caso nem está usando um vetor dentro de outro. Está usando um elemento de um vetor com índice de um elemento de outro vetor. É a informação que você tem. Sabe fazer teste de mesa? Isto ajuda entender muita coisa.

Comment: Rs. :) Estou começando a entender. Vou testar.

Comment: A um elemento de `frequency`. Não dá para perceber no exemplo destrinchado que eu eu fiz?

Comment: Desculpe, agora eu vi. Fui um pouco desatenciosa.

Comment: Hum, pelo que entendi ele conta quantas vezes a ocorrência de um número e armazena...no vetor...

Comment: Sim. E não mude a pergunta no meio do caminho.

Comment: Você não quer mais me ajudar bigown?

Comment: Posso ajudar sim, mas em outra pergunta, essa, como ela foi feita originalmente já tem uma solução. Você não pode ir mudando a pergunta para por todos os problemas do código. Se ele ainda tem problema, faça outra pergunta.

Comment: CERTO! ^------^